# Can I / Should I integrate DocuSign with MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, docusignapi

I need to implement electronic signatures from an Access database without using a signature pad.  I do not have an actual document that needs to be signed - just a field on an Access form.  We currently use a Topaz signature pad but are needing to get away from that.
Thanks in advance,
Karen

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. There are several .net api to access DocuSign.

You can use them to create the DocuSign envelope. You will also need to implement something to retrieve the signed envelopes. There are two options:

1. a cron job that calls DocuSign to get all the updated envelopes since the last call
2. a REST service that DocuSign will call to inform your application of every event that happens on your envelopes.

If you want to use the second option, your REST service should be open to Internet (you can find the subnet to open in the DocuSign documentation).

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign is used to sign documents, not data. Since your database is holding a form's worth of data, I suggest that you:

1. Create a template in DocuSign that represents the Access form
2. When you make the Envelopes: Create call to DocuSign, populate the template's data fields with the data from the Access db.
3. The result will be a signing request that looks like the form in your database.
4. Once the document is signed in DocuSign, you can record the envelope ID in Access. It can then be used to view the signed document. Or you can download the signed documents and store them locally.

Ask further questions here if you have any difficulties.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The first reply left me very lost.  I am a long time Access programmer and not much more.  To follow your steps, which sound good, where do I even start?  I believe my doctor has a DocuSign account so I assume I create the template in there but it is the link into Access I don't know about.  I saw on the DocuSign site that there are costs to the API of about $3.00 per signature and it does not get cheaper, the more you buy?

Comment: Hi, start at the [DocuSign Developer Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center). Check out the recipes. Developer accounts are free. If you decide to use a template, only some API plans include that feature. As an alternative, use Access to create a pdf file, then send it to DocuSign to be signed. Re costs--there are different plans with different features. Costs do go down as you send more envelopes but they go up if you need more features.