# MS Access Report to Docusign

Tags: ms-access, docusignapi, docusignconnect

Have an MS Access report and need to have customer E-Sign it. what is the easiest/best way to get this done? was looking for automation as much as possible to limit steps for the user.

Comment: Have you done any research? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660107/can-i-should-i-integrate-docusign-with-ms-access, https://www.capterra.com/sem-compare/digital-signature-software/?utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc, https://www.microsoftaccessexpert.com/Microsoft-Access-Signature-Capture-Database.aspx, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to find how to generate your MS Access Report and what is the output. Let's say it's a PDF.
You then upload this PDF to DocuSign, which you can do using the eSignature REST API.
To see code that takes a PDF and sends it for signature - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-email-remote/
This includes code examples in 8 languages.

You will need a DocuSign Developer account and OAuth key(s) to use DocuSign functionality for testing and development.